# Prevent falsy request from React Router loader function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, aws-amplify

I use React Router 6.4.2 and it's API - `createBrowserRouter`.
I have a default request that should be done only once when user reach main route (`'/'`).
Request requires auth token (Amplify) so i use protected routes. No token - redirect to `'./auth/`.

Router:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: (
      <RequireAuth>
        <AppLayout />
      </RequireAuth>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        loader: getDefaultData,
        element: <MainPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '/auth', element: <Authenticator /> },
  {
    path: '*',
    element: <NotFoundPage />,
  },
]);

export const AppRouter = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<AppLoader centered />} />;
};
```

RequireAuth:

```
export const RequireAuth = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { route } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.route]);
  if (route !== 'authenticated') {
    return <Navigate to="/auth" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }
  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

GetDefaultData:

```
export const getDefaultData = async () => {
  store.dispatch(
    getData({
      someVariables,
    })
  );
};
```

**What i faced:** when **not authenticated** user try to reach main route (`'/'`), he reach it for a moment before he will be redirected to `'./auth/` and React Router run `getDefaultData` from `loader` that fails on getting-auth-toker step.

**What i expect:** React Router will skip `getDefaultData` for that case. Looking for a way how to tell React Router about that in a beautiful way.

P.S. I know that i can add auth check with return inside `getDefaultData` function (generally it happens but not from scratch but on getting-auth-token).
I know about `shouldRevalidate` but not sure that it can help me in that case.

UPD. provided a codesandbox for that
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-matsumoto-cdbtow?file=/src/index.tsx
Simply try remove '/auth' from url manually and check console.
UPD. created an issue about that https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9529

Comment: Can `getDefaultData` check for the authenticated user/token prior to making requests? Can you share all relevant code you are working with and trying to use as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned in P.S. section: i can do this in function, and generally it happens when i try to get token to add it to my request. 
Like this function runs but crashes before the request is sent with the error: No current user (as expected).
And the question is - how to tell React router not to run this finction at all!
As we do not care about function itself or auth mechanic, i think that no more code evolved in this situation. But can you tell in what parts you are interested in?

Comment: I suppose I was trying to imply that if the `getDefaultData` function has the capability to know whether or not it's in a state to make valid requests that it should do that check and only make valid requests. RRD doesn't conditionally call loaders AFAIK.

Comment: Added `getDefaultData` shape.
So generally if i will do something like
```const session = await Auth.currentSession();
    if(!session) return;
``` 
in the very begining of a function - it will do one request to prevent another =)
That generally happens but a little bit later in middlewares when i'm adding token to headers.

Comment: But i declare if i expect that request should happen on a level above the loader declaration. Looks like ProtectedRoutes do not protect anymore ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Matt Brophy in github:
*Fetching is decoupled from rendering in 6.4, so loaders run before any rendering logic. You should lift your "requires authorization" logic out of the RequireAuth component and into your loaders and redirect from there. Redirecting during render is too late 
Also note that all loaders for a matched route route run in parallel, so you should check in each loader for now (just like in Remix). We plan to make this easier to do in one place in the future.*
Original answer:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9529

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I ran into this today and it is surprising behavior. Basically, you need to protect each loader/action function in addition to conditionally rendering a component. You can take care of conditionally rendering a component tree from the top of the tree only, so all child components won't render (expected), but then you need to protect each loader function (from the top of the route tree, to the leaf of the route tree) with an `if (isLoggedIn)` guard on protected routes. This is bc loaders run in parallel if the route matches, regardless if they end up being rendered.